# How to in angular2 make my longpress directive on a button not trigger a click or router event?

Tags: angular

I have the following longpress directive:

```
//<div (click)="open(item)" [routerLink]="['./myroute']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" long-press (longpress)="select(item)"></div>

import {Directive, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[long-press]'
})
export class LongPressDirective {
  private touchTimeout: any;
  @Output() longpress = new EventEmitter();

  private rootPage: any;

  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('touchstart') touchstart():void {
    this.touchTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.longpress.emit({});
    }, 400);
  }

  @HostListener('touchend') touchend():void {
      this.touchEnd();
  }
  @HostListener('touchcancel') touchcancel():void {
      this.touchEnd();
  }

  private touchEnd():void {
    clearTimeout(this.touchTimeout);
  }
```

Problem is, when I do a longpress, I trigger both the function in (longpress) and (click). How can I make it so that I only trigger the "select(item)" method, and not the "open(item)" or navigate to another route if I do a longpress?

Comment: Try this logic. https://jsfiddle.net/reduardo7/u47ok38e/ and convert to angular

Comment: That is angular1, am looking for an angular2 solution.

Comment: You can use the logic and convert to angular. The semantics of touchevents dont change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of touchstart use mousedown and up as below

```
import {
  Directive,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  HostBinding,
  HostListener
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[long-press]' })
export class LongPress {

  @Input() duration: number = 400;

  @Output() onLongPress: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onLongPressing: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onLongPressEnd: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  private pressing: boolean;
  private longPressing: boolean;
  private timeout: any;
  private mouseX: number = 0;
  private mouseY: number = 0;

  @HostBinding('class.press')
  get press() { return this.pressing; }

  @HostBinding('class.longpress')
  get longPress() { return this.longPressing; }

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown(event) {
    // don't do right/middle clicks
    if(event.which !== 1) return;

    this.mouseX = event.clientX;
    this.mouseY = event.clientY;

    this.pressing = true;
    this.longPressing = false;

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.longPressing = true;
      this.onLongPress.emit(event);
      this.loop(event);
    }, this.duration);

    this.loop(event);
  }

  @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove(event) {
    if(this.pressing && !this.longPressing) {
      const xThres = (event.clientX - this.mouseX) > 10;
      const yThres = (event.clientY - this.mouseY) > 10;
      if(xThres || yThres) {
        this.endPress();
      }
    }
  }

  loop(event) {
    if(this.longPressing) {
      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.onLongPressing.emit(event);
        this.loop(event);
      }, 50);
    }
  }

  endPress() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.longPressing = false;
    this.pressing = false;
    this.onLongPressEnd.emit(true);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseup')
  onMouseUp() { this.endPress(); }

}
```

Comment: Dumb question, but if I switch to mousedown and up, will it still work the same way on a touchscreen?

Comment: Use your own click event in LongPress and if the longPress was happent dont emit anything else emit your click event

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for - you should make this available through NPM, the options available at the moment don't achieve the desired result - this directive is spot on - saved me hours!